# Получение списка таблиц postgres

Tags: postgresql

Как написать запрос на получение списка таблиц, а лучше сразу на поиск определённой таблицы в БД? Если не находит, то пусть вернёт false, а если находит таблицу — true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_regclass('some_table') is not null;
```

Comment: Как-то сложно. `select to_regclass('some_table')  is not null;`

Comment: @Мелкий исправил.